# Default constructor with interface injection along with Parameterized Constructor in same class

Tags: c#

```
        public class xyz
          {    

            private readonly ICheck _checker; 

            private readonly IChecker checker;.

            public xyz()
            {
            _checker = checker.Create<xyz>(); //default constructor initialization
            };

            public xyz(string value)
            {
            validateIt(value);//parameter Constructor
            <!--do something-->
            }


            private static void validateIt(string value){
            var msg= "Is not Valid";   //static method which will log the msg
            _checker.log(msg);
            }

        }
```

//Now the problem is that default constructor is not working(C# code)
 //1.checker is initializing as null
 //2. unable to get reference of _checker in static method(even if problem 1 is resolved)

Comment: it's most likely because you don't have a default constructor

Comment: You have 4 separate language tags here, correct your tags and clarify exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Please choose a language.

Comment: I have now changed to default one @Stultuske

Answer (score 0):

First, nitpicking:
A **default constructor** is the constructor provided by the c# compiler when you don't specify a constructor in your class code.
You can't specify a default constructor in your class code. you can specify a constructor that doesn't take any parameters, but it's not going to be "default" anymore.

Once you have specified a constructor, that's the only constructor you have, unless you specify other constructors as well.

Second, if you are initializing your class with one constructor, you don't automatically use other constructors as well. For that you need to use constructor chaining - call one constructor from the other. In your case:

```
public xyz(string value) : this()
{
    // constructor logic goes here
}
```

Third, `private readonly _checker;` will cause a compilation error - you must specify the type of the private member (and in any case, it's defined correctly in the next code line)

Fourth, You can't access instance members from a static member, unless you have a reference to an instance. If you want to use the `_checker` as a static member, it needs to be defined as `static`. otherwise, you either need to pass an instance of `xyz` to your static method or simply make it an instance method:

```
public class xyz
{
    private readonly IChecker checker;

    public xyz()
    {
        // default constructor initialization
        _checker = checker.Create<xyz>();
    };

    public xyz(string value) : this()
    {
        // parameterized Constructor
        validateIt(value);
        //do something
    }

    private void validateIt(string value)
    {
        var msg= "Is not Valid";
        _checker.log(msg);
    }
}
```